# Regex to capture an URL

Tags: regex, powershell

I've extracted an URL from a website in this string form:

```
@{href=http://download.company.net/file.exe}[0]
```

I can't figure out pattern how to get this part out of it: `http://download.company.net/file.exe` so I can use it as URL to download file.

From my point of view the logic would be, that I need to first match "http" as beggining of a string, wildcard inbetween and then match "}", but not include it in final output. So IDK ...`[http]*\}` (I know that this "syntax" of mine is totally wrong, but you get the idea)

Reason I dont want to include "exe" to pattern, is that file extension could be "msi" and I want it to be more universal. Also some good and comprehensive PS regex  article would help me greatly (with inexperience in mind) - I really didnt find any "newbie friendly" or comprehensive enough to understand this topic.

Comment: If you want some documentation on regex in general, [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a good place. It also has [a page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html) on `powershell`'s implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either, use `[regex]::match` or  `-replace`.

In the following example, I capture everything after `href=` that is not a starting curly bracket `}`:

```
'@{href=http://download.company.net/file.exe}[0]' -replace '@{href=([^}]+).*', '$1'
```

**Output:**

```
http://download.company.net/file.exe
```

Comment: Do you think you could break the pattern into smaller "pieces" with explanation, what each part does? Im going to accept your answer anyway, but it would be helpful.

Comment: You can find more information about that specific regex here: https://regex101.com/r/alp941/1

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `-cmatch` or `-imatch` as

```
if ($content -imatch '(?<=href=).*(?=})') {
    $result = $matches[0]
} else {
    $result = ''
}
```

In case of test data, it will return

```
http://download.company.net/file.exe
```

Comment: why are you using the case sensitive match? Also this only returns true or false....

Comment: Good point. I just hinted a way to perform task. please see updated solution.